# Was ist ein "Kurverein"?

Tags: meaning

Kann mir jemand erklären was ein

> Kurverein

ist?

Ich zitiere den Text, wo ich dieses Wort gefunden habe:

> Informationen über den Zustand der Winterspazierwege erhalten Sie bei den örtlichen Kurvereinen oder bei der Ferienregion Engadin.

Vielen Dank

Comment: Ein Kurverein scheint ein eingetragener VErein zu sein, der einen Kurort oder Erholungsort betreibt. Ich kannte den Begriff allerdings bis eben auch noch nicht.

Comment: In Yiddish a kurve is a prostitue (from the Slavic, probably a cognate of "whore") so on quickly reading the passage, I understood that you could learn of the condition of the winter trails by inquiring with the local Union of Prostitutes.

Comment: @MartyGreen Funny but not true. The word is not "kurve-rein" but rather "kur-verein".

Comment: @npst warum ist das keine Antwort??

Comment: @Vogel612 Weil ich dieses "Wissen" einer fünfminütigen Unterhaltung mit Google verdanke denke ich nicht, dass das eine zufriedenstellende Antwort sein kann ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kurvereine wurden im späten Mittelalter ab 14. bis zum 15. Jhd. gegründet und dort wurde der zuständige Kurfürst gewählt. Heute werden diese Vereine traditionell in Gegenden gehalten, die Touristik betreiben.

Speziell dein genannter Kurverein Engadin ist in der Schweiz - zu finden hier: [Kurverein St. Moritz](http://www.stmoritz.ch/winter/service/kurverein/).

Dort stehen auch die Aufgaben des Vereins:

> Aufgaben des Vorstands
>
> - Koordination und Vertretung touristischer Interessen der Leistungsträger von St. Moritz, inbesondere auch gegenüber der Tourismusorganisation Engadin St. Moritz.
> - Strategische und operative Führung der Marke St. Moritz.
> - Zuständig für Innovationen, Visionen und Kurortsleitbild.
> - Genehmigung des Jahresabschlusses zu Händen der Generalversammlung.

Dort steht auch, dass es nicht nur ein Kurverein ist, sondern jetzt ein **Kur- und Verkehrsverein**, ein reiner Kurverein ergibt heute ohne mögliche Kurfürsten keinen Sinn.

Comment: Der [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurverein) erklärt die Kurfürstenvariante so, dass dort Kurverein i.S.v. Kurvertrag gemeint ist (vgl. *sich einigen*), es sich dabei also mitnichten um eine Gruppe handelt. (Das Kur in Kurfürst kommt von mhd. *kiesen* = wählen, noch zu finden in auserkoren und küren, weil er eben ein gewählter Fürst ist.) Diese Sache hat also **nichts** mit einem Verein zu tun, der sich um die Belange eines Kurorts (hier Kur i.S.v. Therapie von lat. *cura* = Sorge, Pflege) kümmert.

Comment: Der Kurfürst heißt nicht so, weil er gewählt ist, sondern weil er zu den Fürsten gehört, die den Kaiser wählen.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist falsch. “Kurvereine” im modernen Kontext haben mit Kurfürsten nichts zu tun, sondern mit Kurorten.